# Trying to implement a low-pass filter with a LNA as an op-amp

Tags: filter, low-pass, cadence

I'm trying to implement a low-pass filter using this circuit configuration:

[image]

I first tried implementing in Cadence using an ideal op-amp:

[image]

At 1 MHz I already have around -2.29 dB, so it's working as intended.

[image]

Then U replaced that ideal op-amp with a LNA that I made:

[image]

Here's what's inside the LNA:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The frequency response doesn't make any sense. I want a response close to the ideal case.

[image]

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 4):

You have a 1uF decoupling capacitor at the input of your LNA. That's why you see a bandpass behavior.

This produces a zero that, in turn, produces a high pass response. Therefore, you have made an amplifier that doesn't let DC through, so your full response has more of a bandpass behavior.